# Como deixar os objetos lado-a-lado vindo do *ngFor?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-api, angular-cli

Eu tenho essa situação:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <!-- 1 Primeiro cartão, 1° objeto -->
    <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
      <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
        </p>
        <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
        <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div>      
  <!-- 2 Segundo cartão, 2° objeto -->
  <!-- 3 Terceiro cartão, 3° objeto -->     
</div>
```

Conforme o código acima eu possuo "3" (três) cartões um do lado do outro, porém meu problema é quando eu coloco o *ngFor conforme o primeiro cartão e eu gostaria que eles ficassem um do lado do outro usando o *ngFor independente de quantos objetos venham do BD. Se eu tirar *ngFor e deixar os cartões com textos quaisquer eles funcionam, ou seja, ficam conforme eu quero na viwer. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: vc esta usando a `class="col-lg-12"` e ela ocupa toda a extensão da tela

Comment: Sim, uso ela dentro de uma `class="row"` acho que é o certo!

Comment: porém quando vc abre os 3 cartões, fica um embaixo do outro

Comment: Sim usando o *ngFor sim, mas se eu tirar ele ai fica certo. Cara se eu achei a solução qual a melhor forma de eu sair desse sem perder meus pontinhos? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Layout de Bootstrap

O [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) funciona com um [sistema de grelhas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) compostas por diversas linhas (`.row`) que depois são compostas por colunas de larguras variadas (ex.: `.col-lg-8`) sendo que cada `.row` tem 12 unidades de largura. Como o seu `.card` está dentro de uma coluna com 12 de largura (`.col-lg-12`) cada `.card` ocupará sempre a largura total da `.row`.

Como tal, para ficarem lado a lado, teria de ter algo como:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

  <!-- 1 Primeiro cartão, 1° objeto -->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
      <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
        </p>
        <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
        <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div> 
  
  <!-- 2 Segundo cartão, 2° objeto -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
      <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
        </p>
        <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
        <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div> 
  
  <!-- 3 Terceiro cartão, 3° objeto -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
      <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
        </p>
        <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
        <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div> 
  
</div>
```

---

### Potencial problema do layout

Ótimo! Agora se abrirmos num ecrã grande aparecem lado a lado! Mas e em tablets ou telemóveis? Irá aparecer uma por linha. Isto tem a haver com o seletor `.col-lg-n` em que ocupará `n` unidades de largura em ecrãs que sejam do tipo Large (>= 992px de largura) - [mais informação sobre isso aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Um exemplo em que ele mostraria sempre 3 itens por linha:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="row">

      <!-- 1 Primeiro cartão, 1° objeto -->
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
          <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>
              <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
            </p>
            <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
            <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div> 
      
      <!-- 2 Segundo cartão, 2° objeto -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
          <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>
              <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
            </p>
            <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
            <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div> 
      
      <!-- 3 Terceiro cartão, 3° objeto -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
          <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>
              <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
            </p>
            <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
            <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div> 
      
    </div>
```

> **Nota**: mesmo estando na mesma `.row`, se a soma dos elementos não der
>   os 12, o Bootstrap continua a colocar os elementos em baixo.

---

### Solução com o Angular

Tendo em conta isto, o mais simple será fazer o `*ngFor*` dentro da sua `.row` com a largura do cartão que queira e deixar o Bootstrap tratar do resto:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">

<div class="card borda-card" *ngFor="let evento of eventos">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <!-- 1 Primeiro cartão, 1° objeto -->
      <a href="/assets/img/2.jpg" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/2.jpg')" class="imagem-card" data-lightbox="2.jpg"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>
          <b>{{ evento.titulo }}</b>
        </p>
        <p class="data-card">{{ evento.data }}</p>
        <p>{{ evento.descricao }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn-mais-card">Saiba mais</a>
      </div>
    </div>       
  </div>          
</div>
```

> **Tenha em atenção** que o espaçamento vertical pode não ficar bem, por isso na sua `.borda-card` acrescentaria uma margem para ter a certeza que eles ficariam bem sem trocar de `.row`.